# SVN client is not working giving error as below

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

host address found in database but Error: requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the
Error: correct associated data being resolved for.

I am able to go to the URL using browser.

Pl help to resolve.

Comment: Something wrong with DNS server. Try ipconfig /flushdns command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a very strange error to say that the name exists, but there are no address records in their DNS.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a [generic Win Socket error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668) **WSANO_DATA 11004**.

The error may occur due to a DNS misconfiguration: an **MX** record is returned but no **A**
record — indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

I advise you to verify your DNS configuration for the VisualSVN Server
machine and local domain in general.

Misconfigured or non-accessible proxy can also result into such issue. E.g. if there is proxy specified in `"%APPDATA%/Subversion/servers"` you should double-check if it's up and running.